# Ubuntu X11: Is it possible to open an X application in another users session

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-12.10, x-server

Is it possible to somehow open an x application on another users display?

Say that i have user A who is logged on to the ubuntu desktop, and user B who is accessing the ubuntu machine via SSH.

I know that it is possible for user B to open an x application locally, but is it possible for user B to open a program (ie firefox) and have it displayed on user A's desktop session?

And if yes, how?

Comment: Related: [How to open an application in running X session](http://superuser.com/questions/602865/how-to-open-an-application-in-running-x-session)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it will depend on your [`xhost`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_xhost.htm) settings. So, if you have connected as userB to a machine that is running an X session owned by userA, you will need to do two things:

1. userA must allow you access:

   ```
   userA@foo $ xhost +
   ```
2. You need to set your `DISPLAY` variable to the remote display:

   ```
   userB@foo $ export DISPLAY=:0;
   ```

Now userB will be able to run graphical programs.

Comment: And that will make user B's xapp appear on user A's screen? Also, is DISPLAY=:0; the actual value, or do i have to do some reading to find out what to set it for? I would assume i would need to some IP address and user stuff there?

Comment: @MartinNielsen yup. That's what you asked for isn't it?

Comment: Yes... yes it was:)

Comment: This questions has been asked already see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/602865/how-to-open-an-application-in-running-x-session). Though in a not so clear fashion.
Is it possible to merge? Or must one of them be tagged as duplicater?

Comment: @wottis flag the question for moderator attention and leave them a message with the duplicate's link. They can choose to merge or not.

Comment: my man entry reports that `xhost +` permits ANY user to use the host X session.  The stdout, says: "...clients can connect from any host."  Is there a method to specify ONE user only or a add a user to the Set of users?